# Android Device Administration API - factory reset, IMEI tracking

Tags: android, tracking, reset, imei

I am developing a security application just have the following questions, couldnt find correct answers.

its a device administration API application which is used for locking stolen phone, erase data, track location.

When happens to the app if the phone is factory reset.

1. will it erase the app as well. is there a way to reactivate the app even after hard reset. so stolen phone can still be traced.
2. If the app is removed, is there an option to trace phone location using IMEI number.
3. How to the prevent the app from deleted when doing a factory reset.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> will it erase the app as well

Yes.

> is there a way to reactivate the app even after hard reset

The user would have to reinstall it and set it up again as a device administrator.

> If the app is removed, is there an option to trace phone location using IMEI number.

Not in standard Android.

> How to the prevent the app from deleted when doing a factory reset.

Build your own device that has your app pre-loaded onto firmware and set up as a device administrator.

Comment: @RaghulanGowthaman: Apparently somebody thinks that "this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful", which is the official rationale for down-voting the question.